# firebase react native throws [ReferenceError: Property 'Proxy' doesn't exist] when I try to push on reatlitme database

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, react-native-firebase

I'm trying to push data using react and firebase realtime database. My setup works fine for reading and updating data but it fails when I try to push.

This is the relevant section of code that fails

```
    try {
      const newReference = database().ref('/testUsers').push();
      console.log('Auto generated key: ', newReference.key);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Not able to push', error);
    }
```

It throws this error:

```
[ReferenceError: Property 'Proxy' doesn't exist]
```

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to fix it. The demo project was the key (https://github.com/mikehardy/rnfbdemo)
First I updated all my react native firebase dependencies to 12.1.0 but the bug was still present only in linux+android.  Then I updated all the dependeties that ware common in my project with the demo project and that fixed my problem. I was using previously react 16.13.1.

before

```
  "dependencies": {
   ...
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "0.63.4",
  
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.8.4",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^1.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^25.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.5.1",
    "jest": "^25.1.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.59.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.13.1"
  },
```

after

```
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.2",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "^7.14.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.64.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.1"
  },
```

@mikehardy Thank you so much for the help and guidance.
https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/5503